# Regularly spaced numbers between bounds without jot

Tags: bash, sequence

I want to generate a sequence of integer numbers between 2 *included* bounds. I tried with `seq`, but I could only get the following:

```bash
$ low=10
$ high=100
$ n=8
$ seq $low $(( (high-low) / (n-1) )) $high
10
22
34
46
58
70
82
94
```

As you can see, the 100 is not included in the sequence.

I know that I can get something like that using `jot`:

```bash
$ jot 8 10 100
10
23
36
49
61
74
87
100
```

But the server I use does not have `jot` installed, and I do not have permission to install it.

Is there a simple method that I could use to reproduce this behaviour without `jot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind launching an extra process (`bc`) and if it's available on that machine, you could also do it like this:

```
$ seq -f'%.f' 10 $(bc <<<'scale=2; (100 - 10) / 7') 100
10
23
36
49
61
74
87
100
```

Or, building on [oguz ismail's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73783742/58808) (but using a precision of 4 decimal places):

```bash
$ declare -i low=10
$ declare -i high=100
$ declare -i n=8
$ declare incr=$(( (${high}0000 - ${low}0000) / (n - 1) ))
$ 
$ incr=${incr::-4}.${incr: -4}
$ 
$ seq -f'%.f' "$low" "$incr" "$high"
10
23
36
49
61
74
87
100
```

Comment: I like the `bc` method, I was hoping for a oneliner and this does the trick! For posterity, here is the command with variables: `seq -f'%.f' $low $(bc <<< "scale=2; ($high - $low) / ($n-1)") $high`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this naive implementation of `jot`:

```
jot_naive() {
  local -i reps=$1 begin=${2}00 ender=${3}00
  local -i x step='(ender - begin) / (reps - 1)'
  for ((x = begin; x <= ender; x += step)); do
    printf '%.f\n' ${x::-2}.${x: -2}
  done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` for that:

```bash
awk -v reps=8 -v begin=10 -v end=100 '
    BEGIN{
        step = (end - begin) / (reps-1);
        for ( f = i = begin; i <= end; i = int(f += step) )
            print i
    }
'
```

```
10
22
35
48
61
74
87
100
```

Comment: @leleogere that is also the case here

Answer (score 1):

***UPDATE 1*** ::: fixed double-printing of final row due to difference less than tiny value of `epsilon`

- to maintain directional consistency, rounding is performed based on sign of `final` :

  —- e.g. if `final` is negative, then any rounding is done as if the current step value (`CurrSV`) is negative, regardless of sign of `CurrSV`

———————————————

while i haven't tested every single possible edge case, i believe this version of the code ***should*** handle both positive and negative rounding properly, for the most part.

that said, this isn't a `jot` replacement at all - it only implements a very small subset of the steps counting feature instead of being a full blown clone of it:

```
{m,g}awk '
function __________(_) { 
    return -_<+_?_:-_ 
}
BEGIN {
   CONVFMT = "%.250g"; OFMT = "%.13f"
     _____ = (_+=_^=_______=______="")^-_^!_ 
} { 
      ____ = (((_=$(__=(___=$NF)^(_<_)))^(_______=______="")*___\
              )-(__=$++__))/--_
   _________ = (_____=(-(_^=_<_))^(________=+____<-____\
                           )*(_/++_))^(++_^_++-+_*_--+-_)
   if (-___<=+___) {
           _____=__________(_____)
       _________=__________(_________)
   }
   do { print    ______, 
              ++_______, int(__+_____), -____+(__+=____) 
   } while(________? ___<(__-_________) : (__+_________)<___)

   print ______, ++_______, int(___+_____), ___, ORS  

}' <<< $'8 -3 -100\n8 10 100\n5 -15 -100\n5 15 100\n11 100 11\n10 100 11'
```

|

```
 1 -3 -3
 2 -17 -16.8571428571429
 3 -31 -30.7142857142857
 4 -45 -44.5714285714286
 5 -58 -58.4285714285714
 6 -72 -72.2857142857143
 7 -86 -86.1428571428572
 8 -100 -100 

 1 10 10
 2 23 22.8571428571429
 3 36 35.7142857142857
 4 49 48.5714285714286
 5 61 61.4285714285714
 6 74 74.2857142857143
 7 87 87.1428571428572
 8 100 100 

 1 -15 -15
 2 -36 -36.2500000000000
 3 -58 -57.5000000000000
 4 -79 -78.7500000000000
 5 -100 -100 

 1 15 15
 2 36 36.2500000000000
 3 58 57.5000000000000
 4 79 78.7500000000000
 5 100 100 

 1 100 100
 2 91 91.1000000000000
 3 82 82.2000000000000
 4 73 73.3000000000000
 5 64 64.4000000000000
 6 55 55.5000000000000
 7 47 46.6000000000000
 8 38 37.7000000000000
 9 29 28.8000000000000
 10 20 19.9000000000000
 11 11 11 

 1 100 100
 2 90 90.1111111111111
 3 80 80.2222222222222
 4 70 70.3333333333333
 5 60 60.4444444444445
 6 51 50.5555555555556
 7 41 40.6666666666667
 8 31 30.7777777777778
 9 21 20.8888888888889
 10 11 11
```

Comment: I was not able to make it work (I tried `awk`, `gawk` and `mawk`). To be honest, this bunch of code and lines look quite scary and I am completely unable to debug this on my own ^^

Comment: @leleogere : that code is entirely stand alone - show me the error message when u try to paste that in to terminal. try it again - i think i found the place where the server auto mangled the decrement syntax. of course don't run it as `{m,g}awk ….` - that meant either `mawk` or `gawk`

Comment: Works now! I had indeed an error on that line, I did try to replace it with a single `-` but apparently it needed two of them. What are all those underscores tho? Are they variables?

Comment: @leleogere : one is a function - shouldn't be hard to guess what that function does, rest are variables, and any variable not previously declared has the value of either empty string (if used in string context), or numeric zero (if used in numeric context). most of that extra code was deal with the annoying nuances of rounding when it's negative, or when the sequence jumps signs.

Comment: Maybe there is a reason no one believes you don't you think? When I read your code, I don't have any clue about what is going on. I'm not familiar with `awk`, but I am with other languages, so I should be able to roughly understand how this function is supposed to work. Right now I'm just seeing a mess of underscores. I am not able to tell if `_____` is the same as `______` without actually manually counting the underscores, and even after that, I have no clue what they store as they don't have any meaningful name.

Comment: @leleogere : no one believes me on this one, but ur own coding skills would jump immeasurably when u stop letting named vars constrain your perspective - take out the noise, and it's much easier to get a high level view of what it's supposed to do. personally, i don't see how naming them first from `a` to `z` then from `alpha` to `omicron` is any more helpful. Best case in point - `FS` - it's far more useful not to think of it as `"field seps / fields"` but more like a piano - `$0` is all 7 octaves, white keys r ur fields, black keys r ur seps - don't `"write code"`- compose an `awk` score

Comment: @leleogere : i wasn't trying to troll u - i literally write code like that style for myself these days. but it did made u study my code more carefully, so hopefully ur `awk` skills would've improved quite a bit afterwards. 2 underscores is `start`, 3 underscores is `end/final`, 4 underscores is the floating point increment/decrement, 5 underscores is either plus or minus half (for rounding purposes), 6 underscores is just empty string, 7 underscores is an incrementing counter, and that function is just absolute value

Comment: If this method works for you then use it. However, I strongly believe that when you write code that needs maintenance (maybe by someone else than you), you just can't write like that, people are not supposed to guess what you are doing. Same when you try to help people, quite frankly, I have absolutely no way to understand what you are trying to do in this code without studying it for dozens of minutes. With named variables (and it is possible to name them as you just did in your comment), it would be far easier to understand the overall idea.

Comment: And it did not make me study your code more carefully. It did not work on the first try, I tried a fix that did not work, and if you hadn't fixed it by yourself, I would just have given up as I don't understand the code. I have absolutely no means of trying to debug that kind of code if it's not clear what each variable is supposed to do. And by the way I have no idea how you are able to distinguish between 6 or 7 underscores at a glance (but maybe it's just me)

Comment: @leleogere : do it a few more times and it becomes second nature. with named variables, it's hard for anyone to re-use temp variables that are no longer needed, and you end up with far more temp variables than absolutely necessary - e.g. once you've split a string into an array and don't care for original input string anymore, that variable is thoroughly wasted when in fact it can instantly be re-used for individual array elements instead if it weren't named.

Comment: Maybe it's slightly more efficient, but you can say whatever you want, for someone exterior, it drastically reduces readability and understanding of your code. For long-term projects, you probably want to have code as clear as possible

Comment: @leleogere : "slightly"  is putting it mildly - yesterday i was benchmarking 4 different ways to write leap year function - apparently, for `gawk-gmp`, the fastest to slowest is like 3x difference in speed, so u can see how small inefficiencies can really pile up. when properly optimized, `awk` scripting code easily rival even compiled C-code binaries, let alone `perl` or `python`

Comment: I would be curious to see what is the difference in speed between a script with well-chosen variable names and a script with underscore variable names. I feel like (and it is just my humble opinion), that except in applications where the speed is critical, it will be far easier to maintain code with properly named variables (if you really want to delete variables to free up memory, don't `awk` propose a way to do it manually?). I will always prefer an explicit code that anyone (including myself after a few years of not working on a project) can read and understand at a glance.

Comment: @leleogere : sure i didn't say i write like this for team projects - it's for my own usage. `awk` only gives u a statement to delete array cells or the whole array, not individual variables. and as far as i can tell, variables aren't being garbage collected away when you're still in the middle of the same function. i mean the only thing i've written in `awk` that's meaningfully faster than both `gnu` and `bsd` counterparts is a `wc` replacement

Comment: @leleogere : as for speed : `rows = 1. | UTF8 chars = 930062788. | bytes      = 930062788.` `( pvE 0.1 in0 < jtest_4x.txt |  mawk2x 'BEGIN { _^=FS=RS (OFS=""); RS="^$" } ($!NF = mod3($_))^!_' )  7.64s user 0.81s system 100% cpu 8.439 total

     1 1` :::: can you calculate the `mod % 3` of a single integer spanning `930,062,787` decimal digits in 8.44 secs ? `awk` can

Comment: @leleogere : by comparison, `gawk 5.1.1 with GMP` took `1 minute 21.37secs`, `perl 5.34` returned a `NaN` cuz it couldn't even handle it, and i had to kill `python3` after 3 minutes cuz it still hasn't returned. so do u think that's `"slightly more efficient"`, or orders of magnitude difference ?

Comment: @leleogere : https://i.imgur.com/eT44hPp.png this is the reason why underscores makes it super easy to view the entire code's flow

Comment: Glad it is easy for you, but it is completely incomprehensible to me